# VS Code - Compare metadata in different orgs

Tags: code-coverage, vs-code, visualstudiocode

The one thing that Eclipse IDE seemed to do well that I've not yet worked out in VS Code is comparing metadata in different orgs.

Using VS Code, I know how to compare files which are in the same project, but it seems that different orgs always need to be different projects. Is there an easy way to do this? We have multiple sandboxes which occassionally get a little bit out of sync and a quick code compare really helps take the mystery out of where the differences have cropped up.